# Немогу подключиться к VNC серверу

Tags: linux, сервер, debian, клиент-сервер, vnc

Установил  VNC server на debian 9.

устанавливал  vncserver  по [статье](https://linux-notes.org/ustanovka-vnc-server-na-debian-ubuntu-linux-mint/)

```
# apt-get install vnc4server
# adduser vncuser
# su - vncuser
# vncserver
```

последующие команды не выполнял.

После перезагрузил компьютер и запустил сервер:

```
root@R2CPU:/# vncserver
hostname: Temporary failure in name resolution
Cleaning stale pidfile '/root/.vnc/:1.pid'!

New ':1 (root)' desktop at :1 on machine

Starting applications specified in /etc/X11/Xvnc-session
Log file is /root/.vnc/:1.log

Use xtigervncviewer -SecurityTypes VncAuth -passwd /root/.vnc/passwd :1 to connect to the VNC server.
```

также ip:

```
root@R2CPU:/# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.16.8.169  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.16.8.255
        ether 00:1f:f2:00:00:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 345202  bytes 45118759 (43.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 10  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 55722  bytes 2384152 (2.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 18086  bytes 1717568 (1.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 18086  bytes 1717568 (1.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

НО почему то не заходит :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

пингуеться

```
comp@comp0:~$ ping 172.16.8.169
PING 172.16.8.169 (172.16.8.169) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.16.8.169: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.31 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.8.169: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.30 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.8.169: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=1.34 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.8.169: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=1.33 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.8.169: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=1.33 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.8.169: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=1.26 ms
^C
--- 172.16.8.169 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5006ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.263/1.480/2.314/0.374 ms

comp@comp0:~$ ping www.ya.ru
PING ya.ru (87.250.250.242) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ya.ru (87.250.250.242): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=3.67 ms
64 bytes from ya.ru (87.250.250.242): icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=3.54 ms
^X64 bytes from ya.ru (87.250.250.242): icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=3.57 ms
64 bytes from ya.ru (87.250.250.242): icmp_seq=4 ttl=55 time=3.55 ms
^C
--- ya.ru ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3005ms
```

Вот вывод **netstar** на **сервере** :

```
root@R2CPU:/# netstat -a | more
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 localhost:5901          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ssh             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
udp        0      0 192.168.1.111:36388     10.0.132.7:domain       ESTABLISHED
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     6240     @/tmp/.X11-unix/X1
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     4186     /var/run/dbus/system_
bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    2976     /run/systemd/notify
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    2978     /run/systemd/cgroups-
agent
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2982     /run/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     2993     /run/udev/control
unix  6      [ ]         DGRAM                    2997     /run/systemd/journal/
dev-log
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     3003     /run/systemd/journal/
stdout
unix  7      [ ]         DGRAM                    3005     /run/systemd/journal/
socket
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    6092     /run/user/0/systemd/n
otify
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     6096     /run/user/0/systemd/p
rivate
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     6101     /run/user/0/bus
```

вот попытка подключиться **клиентом** :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот вывод **netstar** на **клиенте** :

```
comp@comp0:~$ netstat -a | more
Активные соединения с интернетом (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address Foreign Address State      
tcp        0      0 localhost:domain        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ssh             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:ipp           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 comp0:49318             stackoverflow.com:https ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 comp0:40194             104.18.35.106:http      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 comp0:45424             arn11s04-in-f3.1e:https ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 comp0:54914             arn09s19-in-f14.1:https ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 comp0:51938             arn09s19-in-f10.1:https ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 comp0:59250             srv131-129-240-87:https ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 comp0:40202             104.18.35.106:http      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 comp0:39880             104.18.226.52:https     TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 comp0:58238             upload-lb.esams.w:https ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 comp0:40886             104.16.220.96:https     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 comp0:50126             stackoverflow.com:https ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 comp0:40200             104.18.35.106:http      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 comp0:55352             arn09s10-in-f10.1:https ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 comp0:34250             xx-fbcdn-shv-01-a:https ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 comp0:39232             fra07s64-in-f164.:https ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      1 comp0:51338             192.168.178.60:21567    SYN_SENT   
tcp        0      0 comp0:39424             edge-star-mini-sh:https ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 comp0:39886             104.18.226.52:https     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 comp0:53674             text-lb.esams.wik:https ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 comp0:36450             srv67-190-240-87.:https ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 comp0:38284             192.229.233.50:https    ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 comp0:59914             104.17.65.4:https       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 comp0:40204             104.18.35.106:http      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 comp0:48026             ec2-34-214-112-79:https ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 [::]:mysql              [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:1716               [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ip6-localhost:ipp       [::]:*                  LISTEN     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ipp             0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:46914           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 localhost:domain        0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:bootpc          0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:mdns            0.0.0.0:*                          
udp6       0      0 [::]:1716               [::]:*                             
udp6       0      0 [::]:57344              [::]:*                             
udp6       0      0 [::]:mdns               [::]:*                             
raw     3072      0 0.0.0.0:icmp            0.0.0.0:*               7          
raw     4608      0 0.0.0.0:icmp            0.0.0.0:*               7          
raw6       0      0 [::]:ipv6-icmp          [::]:*                  7          
raw6       0      0 [::]:ipv6-icmp          [::]:*                  7          
raw6       0      0 [::]:ipv6-icmp          [::]:*                  7          
Активные сокеты домена UNIX (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Путь
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     33473    @/tmp/.ICE-unix/1467
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    31874    /run/user/1000/system
d/notify
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    28042    /run/user/121/systemd
/notify
```

---

увы но у меня нету директории `/etc/vncserver/` файла `vncservers.conf`,
у меня обрезанный debian9 без монитора.
У меня есть файл `/etc/vnc.conf`

На клиенте выполнил команды :

```
comp@comp0:~$ nc localhost 5901
comp@comp0:~$ telnet localhost 5901
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
comp@comp0:~$
```

---

На `vnc server`-e открываем `/etc/X11/Xvnc-session` :

```
#! /bin/sh

test x"$SHELL" = x"" && SHELL=/bin/bash
test x"$1"     = x"" && set -- default

vncconfig -iconic &
$SHELL -l <<EOF
exec /etc/X11/Xsession "$@"
EOF
vncserver -localhost -kill $DISPLAY
```

добавил надпись `-localhost` 
и перезагрузил `vnc server`

Comment: смотри `netstat`'ом на каком порту/адресе сервер слушает... т.к. ты не написал, что что-то настраивал, то скорей всего он слушает по умолчанию на `localhost`'е...

Comment: Для начала, этот самый 192.168.1.111 хотя бы пингуется?

Comment: Всё страньше и страньше. А если на хосте сделать так: `nc localhost 5901` или `telnet localhost 5901`?

Comment: @Oxyd я хочу чтоб работало по `vnc` , я могу выложить текст из файла `/etc/vnc.conf` но не думаю что это имеет смысл

Answer (score 1):

Ну поехали искать где косяк...

1. Попинговать хост
2. Если пингуется, на хосте запустить команду `sudo lsof -i4@0.0.0.0:5900`
3. И да, для VNC порт по умолчанию 5900.

PS: Выяснили что у вас проблема на втором шаге:

> Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
>   tcp        0      0 localhost:5901          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

В Local Address вместо localhost должно быть 0.0.0.0 или айпишник вашего хоста. Подозреваю что по описанию в той статье, вы сделали вот это:

> sudo vim /etc/vncserver/vncservers.conf
>   Нужно добавить опцию «-localhost»

Уберите. Или делайте подключениее через SSH как там описано.

Comment: Ага, у вас ещё и более замороченный в плане настройки tigerVNC...

Comment: Ключ -localhost не нужен... Вообще лучше брать [доку на арчвики](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TigerVNC).